# compile gpu samples at ubuntu by terminal

Tags: opencv, cuda, nvidia, ubuntu-13.10

I have installed all the necessary programs to compile opencv with Nvidia (GPU), I have installed the drivers, CUDA tool kit, libraries_sdk, & finally OpenCV.

I have succeeded to compile the OpenCV C & CPP samples by compiling buildall.sh. now I need to compile the GPU samples.

my question is: What is the Ubuntu 13.10 terminal command needed to compile the GPU OpenCV Samples, for example "optical_flow.cpp"?

Comment: if you want one of my tries ,here is a one -terminal command-:

g++ optical_flow.cpp -o optical_flow `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lopencv_gpu .....

and the error is  : opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: You'll need to locate where the file `opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp` is on your machine, and then add a switch to tell the compiler how to find it, for example `-I/home/user-me/my_opencv`

Comment: ok look , i will give you the full path but i need the command ,

desktop/Opencv/Opencv2.4/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp ........ btw , i did that but i think there is something in the command not in the link so if u can send me the full command ,also I'm new in linux ^_^